# Database Design - when to split data into multiple tables?

Tags: database-design, database-partitioning

I have a table of Animals:

> **Animals**
>   Id  Name
>   1   Dog
>   2   Cat
>   3   Rabbit

Each animal has a portfolio therefore I have two methods of defining the database tables.

***METHOD 1:***

**Portfolio**
Id  AnimalId  Date
1    1        01/01/2001
   2    2  20/03/2009
3    3        05/03/2009
 4    1        01/04/2005

***METHOD 2:***

**DogPortfolio**
Id Date
1  01/01/2001
2  01/04/2005

**CatPortfolio**
Id Date
1  20/03/2009

**RabbitPortfolio**
Id Date
1  05/03/2009

> Which method is preferable? Bear in mind that this is a contrived example and in reality I will be storing ~ 10k rows of data per portfolio.

Comment: 10K rows od data per porfolio is a trivial amount of data and certainly not a justification to partition the tables.

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly go with method 1.

Because Portfolios are the same for each kind of animal then they should be in a table together.  If Dog portfolios were different to rabbit portfolios then you might want to consider something more like method 2.

**Method 1** can also be extended so you can add 1 row

4 Fish

and the rest of the structure carries on working.  With method 2 you would have to create a table (e.g FishPortfolio) every time a row was added to your animals table.

Pretty much every time you come up with a solution that would involve creating Permanent Storage tables at runtime it is a terrible idea.

Make sure that you include both PortfolioID and AnimalID in your indexes.

Comment: Would your opinion be the same if there were only these 3 types of animals (in the word!)? I.e. I don't envisage having more animals in my database.

Comment: Yes, it would be the same. Creating separate tables is silly at best and a query nightmare at worst.